# Verify an user role against an Spring RoleHierarchy

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, java-17

I'm using Spring 3.1.x and trying to figure out how to validate a hierarchy against an Spring `RoleHierarchy` Bean defied like this:

```java
    @Bean
    public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
        RoleHierarchyImpl hierarchy = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
        hierarchy.setHierarchy("ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER\n" 
            + "ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_EDITOR\n" 
            + "ROLE_EDITOR > ROLE_USER");
        return hierarchy;
    }
```

and an enum (probably don't need both):

```java
public enum UserRoles {

    ROLE_ADMIN("ROLE_ADMIN"),
    ROLE_EDITOR("ROLE_EDITOR"),
    ROLE_USER("ROLE_USER");

    UserRoles(String roleUser) {
    }
}
```

I have an REST endpoint called `updateRole` where a User should be able to update which roles the User belong to. However there are a few rules to this (not complete):

- You can't upgrade your own Roles e.g. you can't update your own Roles to `ROLE_ADMIN` if you have the `ROLE_EDITOR` or `ROLE_USER` roles.
- A User with `ROLE_EDITOR` can't become `ROLE_ADMIN`. However the User can add `ROLE_USER`
- If you have `ROLE_ADMIN` you can do anything :-)

Any great ideas on how top accomplish this? Or perhaps without using the already defined hierarchy?

Trying to learn Spring and Java

Thanks
Andy